# let user visit all html pages randomly assigned, making sure no page is repeated jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an a web-based experiment that has over 90 pages (divided into categories etc with mainly 6 groups)Now, the subjects/users have to go through all the pages but randomly assigned starting points..Thanks to stackoverflow I have the following..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pages = [
        "page1.html",
        "page2.html",
        "page3.html"
        "page4.html"
        "page5.html"
        "page6.html"
    ];

    function randomPage() {
        return pages[Math.round(Math.random() * (pages.length - 1))];
    }

    location.href= randomPage();
</script>
```

this does the randomization and opens a random page everytime however, I want to

1.Make sure the page(s) are not repeated

2.Each user Visits all pages

thanks in advance

Comment: Shuffle the array > save it in local storage > browse one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On starting page

```
const maxPages = 6;
const startingPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxPages) + 1;//Random number between 1 and maxPages

sessionStorage.setItem("startingPage", startingPage);
window.location("page"+ startingPage + ".html");
```

On pageXX.html

```
var startingPage = parseInt(sessionStorage.getItem("startingPage"));
//Check if startingPage is the number for next page.
```

Comment: This won't work correctly, since `localStorage` only stores strings, not `Array`s. You'll have to serialize and unserialize the data as it goes in and out of the storage. Also, `sessionStorage` would probably be more suitable for this. Thirdly, it might be better to just store the shuffled indices in the storage, to save space. And - slightly out of scope, sure - but one should consider what happens if the page list is changed.

Comment: @AKX Agree with your concerns. I have fixed the critical ones. I'll the leave the rest for OP to consider.

Comment: hi, thanks for your replies - and pardon my limited knowledge but do i have a question regarding your solution

Comment: so for example i have pages 1-10 and user gets started from page 7 and goes all the way to 10 and then 1,2,3,4,5,6 but since every page is linked to another in ascending order then how would the page know where to end? as right now i have naturally page 9 finishing it off at page 10 (as they are linked)!! am i making sense ?

Comment: @ricky_79 I misread the question. I thought the user would go through pages in random order. I'll fix the solution.